# Internet Explorer Error : SCRIPT5009: ArrayBuffer is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, browser

I am receiving an error in internet explorer 9 and under which does not occur on other browsers. It's:

> SCRIPT5009: 'ArrayBuffer' is undefined

My code is as follows

```
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
    for(i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
           array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
            }
```

The line which breaks is `var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));`

Does anyone know if there is a solution or workaround for this?  I require my functionality to work in all browsers.

Comment: `ArrayBuffer` isn't supported until IE10 (and I think this shows it: http://caniuse.com/typedarrays)

Comment: did u got the answer. If yes. can u post your answer over here

Comment: Hi, Apologies for the slow reply. I did not get a resolution at the time of my issue so just abandoned using the specific approach at that time.  Hopefully you have been able to find a resolution since.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ArrayBuffer` isn't supported until IE10 (and I think this shows it: http://caniuse.com/typedarrays).

You can use a polyfill, and here's one: https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/typedarray.js

Polyfill taken from: https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill