# Blobs, ArrayBuffers and ArrayBufferViews in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, internet-explorer-9, blob, typedarray

I'm developing a little web application, which fetches binary image data encapsulated in XML nodes by XHR. My current web application is using ArrayBuffers, ArrayBufferViews and Blobs to generate blob urls to show the fetched images in my html documents, which works perfectly fine. I need to support the Internet Explorer 9 (sigh), which doesn't support ArrayBuffers, ArrayBufferViews, Blobs or even TypedArrays.

I found an answer regarding ArrayBuffers and TypedArrays here: [Internet Explorer Error : SCRIPT5009: ArrayBuffer is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545286/internet-explorer-error-script5009-arraybuffer-is-undefined)

But what about Blobs? Any suggestions here? Or maybe (a hint for) a clever workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found another polyfill for blobs: https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js/blob/master/Blob.js But is the usage of polyfills considered a good practise? (Didn't test this one, yet)