# IE9 - Error in function : 'ArrayBuffer' is undefined ReferenceError: 'ArrayBuffer' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, jspdf

I have created an application for downloading `pdf`. the `pdf` is based on an html table.
The application is working fine in all browser but when i run in IE9 i am getting `Error in function : 'ArrayBuffer' is undefined ReferenceError: 'ArrayBuffer' is undefined`. Since IE9 is HTML5 based browser jspdf should work i guess.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/00cvyyuo/4/light/)**

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    pdf.cellInitialize();
    pdf.setFontSize(10);
    $.each($('#customers tr'), function (i, row) {
        if ($(row).text().trim().length !== 0) {
            $.each($(row).find("td, th"), function (j, cell) {
                var txt = $(cell).text().trim() || " ";
                var width = (j == 4) ? 40 : 70;
                if (j == 7) {
                    width = 120;
                }
                if(i==0)
                {
                    pdf.setFontStyle('bold');
                }
                else
                {
                    pdf.setFontStyle('normal');
                }   
                    pdf.cell(10, 10, width, 18, txt, i);             
            });
        }
    });

    pdf.save('sample-file.pdf');
}
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: *"**Browser Compatibility**

jsPDF will work in IE6+\*, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safari 3+, Opera. For IE9 and below, we lazily load a Flash shim called Downloadify which enables the files to be downloaded. (Current build does not have IE6-9 shim enabled)."* -[jsPDF page](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

Comment: so what will i need to do

Comment: That I don't know, maybe enable the shim?

Comment: how to enable the shim for IE9

Comment: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/master/libs/Downloadify

Comment: @Andy should i need only to import that downloadify plugin to my application

Comment: Looks like it. You should read the documentation.

Comment: Hello @AlexMan is it working for you now? I am also having same issue if possible can you please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer Error : SCRIPT5009: ArrayBuffer is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545286/internet-explorer-error-script5009-arraybuffer-is-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to enable downloadify:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jsPDF</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/base64.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jspdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/downloadify/js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/downloadify/js/downloadify.min.js"></script>    
</head>

<body onload="load()">
<h1>jsPDF Downloadify Example</h1>

<p>This is an example of jsPDF using <a href="http://www.downloadify.info/">Downloadify</a>. This works in all major browsers.</p>

<p id="downloadify">
    You must have Flash 10 installed to download this file.
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(){
        Downloadify.create('downloadify',{
            filename: 'Example.pdf',
            data: function(){ 
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.text(20, 20, 'PDF Generation using client-side Javascript');
                doc.addPage();
                doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');
                return doc.output();
            },
            onComplete: function(){ alert('Your File Has Been Saved!'); },
            onCancel: function(){ alert('You have cancelled the saving of this file.'); },
            onError: function(){ alert('You must put something in the File Contents or there will be nothing to save!'); },
            swf: '../libs/downloadify/media/downloadify.swf',
            downloadImage: '../libs/downloadify/images/download.png',
            width: 100,
            height: 30,
            transparent: true,
            append: false
        });
    }
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Use the following code to lazy load Downloadify:

```
<script id="jspdf" src="../jspdf.js"></script>

<script id="lazy">
var jspdfScript = document.getElementByid('jspdf');
var swfobjectScript = document.createElement('script');
var downloadifyScript = document.createElement('script');

swfobjectScript.src = "../libs/downloadify/js/swfobject.js";
downloadifyScript.src = "../libs/downloadify/media/downloadify.swf";

if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  document.documentElement.insertBefore(jspdfScript, swfobjectScript);

  swfobjectScript.onload = function () {
  document.documentElement.insertBefore(jspdfScript, downloadifyScript);
  };

  downloadifyScript.onload = function () {
    load();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: For anyone googling, you can find Downloadify in `libs/Downloadify/` when you download jsPDF