# Displaying binary file (pdf) in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, blob, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to display a binary file using the method suggested in this post [AngularJS: Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app?rq=1). This is working nicely in Chrome and FF, but IE 11 is giving me "Error: Access Denied".
Does anyone know if it has something to do with the Blob object and can point me in the right direction?
Here is my js code:

```
$http.get(baseUrl + apiUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
          .success(function (response) {                  
             var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
             var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
             $scope.pdfContent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
           })
           .error(function () {                        
           });
```

and my html:

```
<div ng-controller="PDFController" class="modal fade" id="pdfModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" onloadstart="">
        <object data="{{pdfContent}}"  type="application/pdf" style="width:100%; height:1000px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Workaround: I finally used [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/), but I would still appreciate it if anyonw can tell me why the above mentioned technique isn't working in IE 11...

Comment: I am having this issue as well, did you ever get it working without the FileSaver.js?

Comment: No I didn't unfortunately...

Comment: I know its late but I have same problem. Can you provide some info to display the pdf from blob?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE9 - Error in function : 'ArrayBuffer' is undefined ReferenceError: 'ArrayBuffer' is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103091/ie9-error-in-function-arraybuffer-is-undefined-referenceerror-arraybuffe)

Comment: For more details and a reference implementation in React JS, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41215607/2556796

Answer (score 8):

IE 11 blocks display of blob, you need to use the following:

```
                    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(someByteArray);
                var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
                }
                else {
                    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    window.open(objectUrl);
                }
```