# how to export table html table to PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I need a help regarding the export of a DIV to PDF.

I already tried to use :
-itext to the backend ( java ) but not rendered CSS ;
-html2canvas to transform the DIV image and JSPDF to add the image to PDF , this scheme funcinou but only for google chorme and IE 11 , and I need to work also in IE 9 & 10. Any tips ?

Comment: Getting something from a browser screen to a pdf file is extremely difficult, especially when it has to work for all browsers.  Are you sure it needs to be done this way?

Comment: good morning, thanks for the reply ! sorry for my " English " of google translator , a few weeks already I'm racking my brain trying to make it work for IE, you know any other way to get a DIV export to PDF? ( I really need to make it work )

Comment: No, I don't. :( If you can't make it work with jsPDF for all browsers, then I think you'll have to just send the data you want in the pdf back to your backend, and redo all of the look-and-feel/layout stuff there to make it look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Javascript library called [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) which is PDF files on client side. They also have [examples](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/) that demonstrates how to use the library. They have an example called addHTML() which might be what you are looking for.

In your case you might want to do something like this:

```
pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('DIV_ID'),function() {
    var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
    $('.preview-pane').attr('src', string);
});
```

On the examples page they write that IE6+, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safara 3+ and Opera should work.

Comment: thanks for the reply ! I already tried to use jsPDF but in IE 9 i get the error "ArrayBuffer is undefined"

Comment: @sergioBertolazo can you include the full error message. Maybe there is something that can help me figure out what might be going wrong. Is the error in the jsPDF source code or in your application source code?

Comment: @sergioBertolazo maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103091/ie9-error-in-function-arraybuffer-is-undefined-referenceerror-arraybuffe)  is the same problem.

Comment: Yes @Jacob, is the same error, i will try this solution thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jsPDF is not supported on IE 9. jsPDF used Downloadify to get around this, but it is no longer supported. You can use a number of polyfills, but they are still being patched (e.g. [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js/issues/41#issuecomment-202545658)).

From personal experience, I never got jsPDF to work in IE 9. It's worth trying if you really need to support IE 9, but be aware that you will have to use multiple polyfills.

Here are the specific issues I encountered - IE 9 does not support the following which are used by jsPDF:

- Blob (use Blob.js)
- atob/btoa
- console.trace (just remove the calls)
- Typed Arrays (try [this](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/typedarray.js))