# jsPDF : Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window' when using images

Tags: jquery, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to simply test if the images would show up on my PDF.

My source I download from Github:

```
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/dist/jspdf.min.js
```

My Code:

```
$(function() {

    // You'll need to make your image into a Data URL
    // Use http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker

    var imgData = 'Too long to enter';
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.setFontSize(40);
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 40, 40);
    doc.output('datauri');
    //doc.save("test.pdf");

})
```

If I use:

```
doc.output('datauri');
```

I give an error in browser:

```
error in function Error (native): Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range. DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.(…)e.foo @ jspdf.min.js?85513E54C9B42FC742889C9B29C03598:279
```

While if I use :

```
doc.save("test.pdf");
```

It works fine, I want to work with doc.output('datauri'), how do I fix this problem? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to export table html table to PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261610/how-to-export-table-html-table-to-pdf)